# library or tool to convert pdf to SilverLight xaml file

Tags: silverlight, xaml, pdf, silverlight-4.0

Is there any library or tool to convert a pdf file to SilverLight xaml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what my [google-fu](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pdf%20to%20xaml&qscrl=1) got me:
http://www.amazedsaint.com/2009/05/pdf-to-xaml-conversion-alternate.html

From that article:

1. Create a new Silverlight Project in Expression Blend.
2. As Expression Blend can import adobe illustrator files, simply rename a **pdf** file's extension from `pdf` to `ai`
3. Clicked `File-> Import Adobe Illustrator files` in Blend, and imported to my active window.

You'll get the whole form imported as graphical paths, preserving the whole layout

Comment: I have got lots of Silverlight path data, do you have an idea to process them an separate them to a piece of real object, such a path for a table, a path for a desk?

Comment: Current version of Blend will also vectorize all your Text, and convert them to Path instead of maintaining them.  I still prefer using Adobe Illustrator with the XAML Export plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install the free XAML Export plugin for Adobe Illustrator (CS, CS2, CS3, or CS4).
   http://www.mikeswanson.com/XAMLExport/
2. Rename your .PDF to .AI (for older versions of Illustrator).
3. Open in Adobe Illustrator.
4. Choose which page (Illustrator can only open one page of your PDF at a time).
5. Export to XAML (choose Silverlight over WPF, it produces better results)
6. Rinse and repeat for other pages.